# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.GameLogs_dbo.Scores_scoreId"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was wondering whether you guys can help me figure out what about my database is casuing the error in the title. I had initialized my database with

```
/* Execute in SQL Server Management Studio prior to building data model(s) */

CREATE DATABASE snakedb; 

GO

USE snakedb;

/*
   Create table of scores of games played. Every game will have a score recorded, but there
   will only be a corresponding name if the user enters one
*/
CREATE TABLE Scores ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      score int NOT NULL,
                      name VARCHAR (50) 
                    );

/* 
    Create table of text logs of the games played. These are reviewed to sniff out cheating.  
*/
CREATE TABLE GameLogs ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                        scoreId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES scores(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
                        logText VARCHAR (8000)
                       ); 

/*
    Table of unique IP addresses that have visited the site. The 4 decimal numbers separated by dots that compose each
    IP address, e.g. the 172, 16, 254 and 1 in 172.16.254.1, correspond to the 4 columns byte1, byte2, byte3 and byte4
*/
CREATE TABLE IPs ( id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                   byte1 tinyint, 
                   byte2 tinyint, 
                   byte3 tinyint, 
                   byte4 tinyint 
                  );

/*
     Table of banned IP addresses 
*/
CREATE TABLE BannedIPs ( id int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                         ipId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES IPs(id)
                        );
```

and then used ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard in Visual Studio to create a model of the database. I then ran

```
Enable-Migrations
```

in the Package Manager Console to get a template `Configuration.cs` for `Seed`ing the database. I filled in the `Seed` function like

```
   protected override void Seed(SnakeGame.Models.SnakeGameData context)
    {

        context.Scores.AddOrUpdate(
            s => s.id,
            new Score() { score1 = 20, name = "Test person 1" },
            new Score() { score1 = 4, name = "Test person 2" },
            new Score() { score1 = 22, name = "Test person 3" },
            new Score() { score1 = 35430, name = "Test person 4" },
            new Score() { score1 = 0, name = "Test person 5" },
            new Score() { score1 = 69, name = "Test person 6" }
        );

        context.GameLogs.AddOrUpdate(
            g => g.id,
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 1, logText = "Test text" },
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 2, logText = "Test text" },
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 3, logText = "Test text" },
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 4, logText = "Test text" },
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 5, logText = "Test text" },
            new GameLog() { scoreId = 6, logText = "Test text" }
        );

        context.IPs.AddOrUpdate(
            i => i.id,
            new IP() { id = 1, byte1 = 50, byte2 = 46, byte3 = 146, byte4 = 231 },
            new IP() { id = 2, byte1 = 172, byte2 = 16, byte3 = 254, byte4 = 1 }
        );

        context.BannedIPs.AddOrUpdate(
            b => b.id,
            new BannedIP() {  id = 1, ipId = 2}
        );
    }
```

I then `DROPped` the database through SSMS to see if I would be able to recreated during this process. I ran

Add-Migration Initial
Update-Database

in Package Manager Console and then received the output

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.GameLogs_dbo.Scores_scoreId". The conflict occurred in database "snakedb", table "dbo.Scores", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Full project: https://github.com/jamkin/Snake

Also, from what I understand, it is possible for me to make this all happen when I build my project, so that I don't have the use Package Manager Console. How do I do that?

Comment: This is a long shot, but you didn't specify an `ON UPDATE` action for your foreign key from `GameLogs` to `Scores`. Supposing you did, would the database respond correctly then?

Comment: Look at the DB if the Score ids are as expected in the GameLog (1, 2 .. 5)